# Unable to find motherboard

Tags: motherboard, bios, uefi

I have tried searching everywhere, but with this model of motherboard I am unable to find any information on it. The reason I am looking for the motherboard is I want to update the bios and want to see if there were any updates for it from intel. This is What Cpu-z returns as the motherboard as well as the command promp check.

Manufacturer: INTEL
Model: E5 INTEL (INTEL Xeon E5/Core i7 DMI2 - C600/C200 Chipset)
Chipset: Intel Sandy Bridge-E
Southbridge: Intel Q67

Comment: What problem do you have that you believe will be fixed with a firmware update?  Typically you shouldn't update the firmware unless something you want to use or something specific was fixed.  Anyways, you have not supplied us enough information to identify your motherboard.  Your question is unanswerable in its current form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Intel Driver Update Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24345/Intel-Driver-Update-Utility) will find all driver updates for you including for the BIOS.